# Why does console tell me that .filter is not a function?

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "I am a string.";

console.log(str.split(''));

var fil = function(val){
return val !== "a";
};

console.log(str.filter(fil));
```

When I run this, it says the str.filter is not a function.

Comment: Because string doesn't have a `filter` method.

Comment: Try: `console.log([...str].filter(fil).join\`\`);`

Answer (score 31):

Because `filter` is an array function (`Array.prototype.filter`), while you are calling it on a string. `str.split` returns an array and doesn't change anything to your `str`. call it like `console.log(str.split('').filter(fil))` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

Because you're invoking the execution of "filter" on str, which is an object without a function called "filter" of its own nor by prototype. Since filter is not present the property's value is undefined, which cannot be invoked because its type is not function.

Answer (score 3):

The String object does not have a filter method and String is immutable.
So in effect `str.split('')` does not change the value of the string but returns a new String which you are not capturing in a variable.

Try,

```
console.log(str.split('').filter(fil));
```