# Property 'role' does not exist on type 'Users[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a database of users, with a property "role" that can be either a `driver` or an `admin`, in my `driver.service`, I am trying to `getUsers` and filter them by `role`, in other words, I just want to get the list of users with the role `driver` but when I write my code it says that the property role does not exist on type `Users[]` although I added it in the class `users.ts`
this is my class:

```
export class Users {
    id: number;
    CIN: number;
    name: string;
    address: string;
    email: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    permis: string;
    prenom: string;
    image: string; 
    modeAuto: number;
    sex: string;
    dateNais: Date;
    role: string;
}
```

This is my service with the Getusers method i tried to modify to use the filter :

```
 public urls = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users'; // url pour la récupération de la partie backend(laravel)

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  //* afficher tous les conducteurs*/

  getUsers (): Observable<Users[]> {
    return this.http.get<Users[]>(this.urls).filter(x => x.role === 'driver').pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log('fetched Users')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Users[]>('getUsers', []))
    );
  }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: you can't paste your whole code here, only post relevant code here.

Comment: Okay my bad, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed your filter condition incorrectly, you cannot use any `rxjs` operator directly on the `Observable` type

```
getUsers (): Observable<Users[]> {
    return this.http.get<Users[]>(this.urls).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log('fetched Users')),
      map((m) => m.filter(x => x.role === 'driver')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Users[]>('getUsers', []))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for the answer, i just changed the position of the filter but it still says the property does not exist on type Users[]

Comment: Can you post the code where it is showing that the property does not exist, the way you have used the filter earlier was completely wrong so you need to correct that first, then you need to look for the actual root cause

Comment: was updating my answer but @eko already posted it, try his way it will work

Comment: Okay i tried his way and it did work , but now the list doesn't show on the browser, i have an error in the console that says : TypeError: users.filter is not a function

Comment: are you importing the filter from somewhere?

Comment: The filter is not imported, it is normal javascript array filter

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780950/why-does-console-tell-me-that-filter-is-not-a-function it may help you

Comment: import { tap, catchError, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
 here is my importation,

Comment: you can remove the filter from imports as we haven't used operators filter, in my previous answer I have used it but now this filter is no longer required

Comment: Yep i removed it, i still dont understand the console error

Comment: that is completely different, you may post a different question with the exact details of your problem